# Linearizing division of two variables

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linearization, nonlinear-programming

For all $i \in I,j\in J$ and $k\in K$, define variables $x_{ij}, z_{ijk}\in\{0,1\}$, $y_{ij}\geq 0$ and constants $c_j, e_{ijk}, d_j, f_j >0$.

We have the following constraint
$$\sum_{j\in J_1}c_j\frac{x_{ij}}{\sum_{k\in K}e_{ijk}z_{ijk}} + \sum_{j\in J_2}c_jf_j x_{ij} = \sum_{j\in J_1}d_j\frac{y_{ij}}{\sum_{k\in K}e_{ijk}z_{ijk}} + \sum_{j\in J_2}d_jf_j y_{ij} \quad \forall i\in I,$$

where $J_1, J_2 \subset J$.

We also know that
$$\sum_{k\in K}e_{ijk}z_{ijk}=1 \quad \forall i\in I,j\in J.$$

Now is there a way to linearize these two components?
$$\frac{x_{ij}}{\sum_{k\in K}e_{ijk}z_{ijk}}, \quad \frac{y_{ij}}{\sum_{k\in K}e_{ijk}z_{ijk}}$$

I saw some interesting answers [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/6264/linearize-a-product-of-binary-variables), [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/2903/how-to-linearize-the-multiplication-of-an-integer-and-a-binary-integer-variable?rq=1) and [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/39/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-a-binary-and-a-non-negative-continuous-variable?noredirect=1&lq=1) but I'm having some problems using them for our problem.

Answer (score 6):

The two denominators are equal to $1$, so just omit the denominators, yielding a linear constraint.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't notice that! Is there a way in general to linearize division of two variables?

Comment: Here is a Taylor series approximation for a function of two variables  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69610/taylor-series-in-two-variables